# Recommended pattern for managing data in Session object

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I need to store a "POCO" class in the Session object. Which pattern would you recommend in terms of storage and performance? (I understand that pattern 2 requires serialization). Thank you.

**Pattern 1 (simplified):**

```
class Location {
    string Country { get { return Session["Country"]; } set { Session["Country]" = value };
    string City { get { return Session["City"]; } set { Session["City]" = value };
}
```

**Pattern 2 (simplified):**

```
class Location {
    string Country { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; }
}

Session.Add("Location", new Location() { ... } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely, positively have to use session state, then I'd vote for pattern 2. It's more ovbious what is happening.

But I sure hope to talk you out of using session state altogether. Can you put something on the page, like an ID or something to look up when the response comes back? Here's why:

- Session state is challenging in a web farm. You might not have one now but...
- Session expires so if a page comes back 'later' you have to handle that.
- Session consumes resources on the server for visitors you may never see again.

So, maybe you can serialize into viewstate?

Answer (score 2):

Performance will (as you note) be better in Pattern 1. However, you now have a *huge* dependency on having a Session - if this class is ever to be used outside of the context of a Web application, then you'll have to change it.

Comment: I'm not sure why performance will be better in #1 but +1 for pointing out the session dependency

Comment: Session data is stored as encoded strings - Pattern 1 is using the Session to store strings (assuming that all data in the object is strings, otherwise this breaks down a little), whereas Pattern 2 is using the Session to store string-encoded type data, adding to the conversion overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Pattern 2 just because it's cleaner. Adding new items to your Location object doesn't change all the calls to Session.Add(objLocation) throughout your code.

If performance is a serious issue, then the serialization overhead might be a problem, but my experience has been that memory is cheap, and big fixing is not. So I'd go with Pattern #2.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern 1 is better for performance, but introduces a heavy dependency on the Session object, as Harper Shelby pointed out.

One way to minimize that dependency is to create an interface for storing and retrieving a session object. Your "real" implementeation of the interface will call into the session as needed. This interface implementation can be provided to your class via dependency injection. Continuing from that, you can inject a "fake" implementation for unit testing purposes - no need to use the real session there.

Answer (score 1):

I use pattern 2. I only store a single object in session, which I cleverly call `SessionData`. I try to keep it as small as possible - just about every member of this object is used on every request. In cases where I need some extra data for a specific task (say, a shopping cart), I have a generic slot where I can add it to my object. When I am done with the extra data, I remove it from the SessionData object, to avoid unnecessary serialization.

Using a single object means that I only have to access Session once for every request. While requesting a single simple item like `Session["City"]` would be faster than getting my relatively large object, since I need the whole thing anyway, I suspect that the single call I make will be faster that making a dozen or more individual calls to the Seession.

Also, if I ever change my session management gadget, I only have a two places to change my code (the get and add functions)